# Wait for fetch in different class

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

I have two classes:

**MazeGenerator.js**

```
constructor(gridsize) {
    this.fetchLevels(gridsize);
}

fetchLevels(gridsize){
    fetch("./data/hardcodedLevels.json")
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
                return data[gridsize-1];
            }
        ).then(grid => this.maakVeld(grid))
}

maakVeld(grid) {
    for (let i = 0; i < grid[0].length; i++) {
        this.maze[i] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
            let wall = (grid[i][j] === 1);
            this.maze[i][j] = new Blok(j, i, wall);
        }
    }
}

returnMaze(){
    return this.maze;
}
```

Which should return a two-dimensional array from a local json file. Grid.js should store this array and use it for further calculations.

**Grid.js**

```
constructor(level) {
    this.generator = new MazeGenerator(level);
    this.veld = this.generator.returnMaze();
    this.grootte = this.veld.length;
}
```

As it is now, `this.veld = this.generator.returnMaze();` is executed before the fetch has finished and gives an error because `this.veld` is undefined.
Is there any way to wait untill the fetch has finished in another class?

Comment: async call, return promise and wait for the the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return promise on constructor and wait in other file. Sample:

```
class Test  {
  constructor() {
    return Promise.resolve([1])
  }
}
const x = new Test()
x.then(console.log)
```

For Your case:

```
constructor(level) {
    this.generator = new MazeGenerator(level);
    this.generator.then( maze => {
      console.log(maze)
    })
  }
```

The correct way, Contractor is to add all the configuration. You should return promise on the method call, after initialization.

```
class MazeRunner {
  constructor(gridsize) {
    this.gridsize = gridsize;
  }
  fetchLevels() {
    return fetch("./data/hardcodedLevels.json")
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => data[this.gridsize - 1])
      .then(this.maakVeld);
  }
  maakVeld(grid) {
    let maze = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < grid[0].length; i++) {
      maze[i][j] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
        let wall = grid[i][j] === 1;
        maze[i][j] = new Blok(j, i, wall);
      }
    }
    return maze;
  }
}
class Test {
  constructor(level) {
    this.generator = new MazeGenerator(level);
    this.generator.fetchLevels().then((maze) => {
      console.log(maze);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to return promise from constructors.

Comment: yeah! Understand. Adding sample.

Answer (score 1):

Add event to the class using `EventEmitter`

Your code would look like this:

```
this.generator = new MazeGenerator(level);
this.generator.on('ready', () => {
  this.veld = this.generator.returnMaze();
  this.grootte = this.veld.length;
});
```

Or the second variant: move request from the constructor to another method, so you can return a promise from it:

```
this.generator = new MazeGenerator(level);
this.generator.prepare().then(() => {
  this.veld = this.generator.returnMaze();
  this.grootte = this.veld.length;
})
```